# Running PHP WebSocket on Ubuntu

Tags: php, sockets

### Introduction

Before getting started with the actual question, I’d like to make a notice of being an extreme beginner to the world of web sockets using PHP. As a matter of fact, I’m still trying to grasp the very basics of it. I do however have lots of experience with sockets overall, from languages such as Java.

Upon doing my research, I stumbled upon the [tutorial from PHP builder](http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html), whereas I think myself to having learned how to set socket connections up using [this simple library](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-WebSockets).

### Problem

Unto the problem we go. For a development server, I have chosen to go with XAMPP—it’ss sort of stayed with me from my Windows days, many years ago. At this very moment, I am using the terminal UI for XAMPP in Ubuntu—meaning, I launch the XAMPP server and then do a `killall` should I ever wish to close it.

In the tutorial mentioned above, you enter this information into your PHP document where you keep your server socket:

```
$server = new Server('192.168.0.8', '8000');
```

The `Server` class being a class extended by the `WebSocketServer` provided in the aforementioned library. You’re then supposed to run the PHP server socket using (with the dollar sign symbolizing terminal input):

```
$ php -q serversocket.php
```

It was suggested somewhere else on *Stackoverflow* that you run the server socket with the `-f` flag instead, but both of them—instead of starting the server socket—prints out the file contents in the terminal.

The PHP I’m using (to attempt running the server socket) is the one you get from running (on Ubuntu):

```
$ sudo apt-get install php
```

I’d assume this to be the regular version of PHP.

I’m honestly probably just being a huge moron, but truly do need help to solve this problem. Have I missed something?

Comment: Example https://github.com/fxstar/PHP-Websockets

Comment: @Breakermind Yes, using the example—running it with the aforementioned it’s displayed into the terminal as the raw text the file contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that was occurring at the time was the PHP code being displayed as raw data in the terminal whenever run. I was using short opening tags at the time `<?` and did have them enabled in the configuration.

I did however, resolve the issue, by rewriting the code to use the full opening PHP tags `<?php`. Perhaps there was more things to configure, maybe the version of PHP I was using was broken. Who knows?